# Why C++ operation priority is different when dealing with objects or primitive types ++a*b/b-- - a

Tags: c++

I confused why the two identical expressions give different results? The only difference is only that in the expression () I use custom primitive wrapper types.

I'm providing code for clarity:
    struct Int {
    int value;

```
Int operator*(Int b) const{
    return Int{value*b.value};
}

Int operator/(Int b) const{
    return Int{value/b.value};
}

Int operator-(Int b) const{
    return Int{value - b.value};
}

const Int& operator++() {
    ++value;
    return *this;
}

Int operator--(int) {
    Int copy{value};
    value--;
    return copy;
    }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Int x) {
    out << x.value;
}

int main(){
    int a = 11; Int A{11};
    int b = 4; Int B{4};
    cout << ++a / b * b-- - a << endl; // 0
    cout << ++A / B * B-- - A << endl; // 4
}
```

Also Clang compiler shows a warning -Wunsequenced but only for the expression with primitive types.

Comment: Suppose it's undefined behavior in C++

Comment: Ok, but why are we getting warning only with primitive types? Does it means that with classes the order of operations is defined?

Comment: Both are undefined, but clang can only detect unsequenced modification for the primitive types - it doesn't "know" that your operators modify the objects.

Comment: Why did you write code that you cannot understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All expressions like `++a / b * b-- - a` have undefined behavior because variables are read from and written to without a [sequence point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) in between.